# Cannot transfer JSON value to Label in SecondViewController

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

I am trying to transfer a JSON value to a label in another view controller, from pressing a button in my Main View Controller.  My first view controller is called 'ViewController' and my second one is called 'AdvancedViewController. The code below shows how I get the JSON data, and it works fine, displays the JSON values in labels in my MainViewController, but when I go to send a JSON value to a label in my AdvancedViewController, I press the button, it loads the AdvancedViewController but the label value is not changed?  I have assigned the label in my AdvancedViewController and I'm not sure why its not working.  I am trying to transfer it to the value 'avc.Label' which is in my advanced view controller

The main label code shows how I get it to work in my MainViewController

Code below:

My Main ViewController:

```
 guard let APIUrl = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + text +  "&appid=e7b2054dc37b1f464d912c00dd309595&units=Metric") else { return }
        //API KEY

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: APIUrl) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else { return }


            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            //Decoder

            do {
                let weatherData = try decoder.decode(MyWeather.self, from: data)

                if (self.MainLabel != nil)
                {
                    if let gmain =  (weatherData.weather?.first?.main) { //using .first because Weather is stored in an array
                        print(gmain)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.MainLabel.text! = String (gmain)
                        }
                    }

                }

                let avc = AdvancedViewController(nibName: "AdvancedViewController", bundle: nil)

                if (avc.Label != nil)
                {
                    if let mTest =  (weatherData.weather?.first?.myDescription) { //using .first because Weather is stored in an array
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            avc.Label.text! = String (mTest)
                                                    }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

In **AdvancedViewController** create variable that store the value of `mTest`

```
class AdvancedViewController: ViewController {

    var test: String!

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let test = test {
            myLabel.text = test
        }
    }

}



let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AdvancedViewController") as! AdvancedViewController
if let mTest =  (weatherData.weather?.first?.myDescription) {
    vc.test = mTest
}
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I can't get any of that code working, it doesn't recognise 'weatherData', it won't accept 'let vc', and it cannot find 'mTest'

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to manipulate another view controller's views. That violates the OO principle of encapsulation. (And it sometimes just plain doesn't work, as in your case.)

Salman told you what to do to fix it. Add a String property to the other view controller, and then in that view controller's viewWillAppear, install the string value into the desired label (or do whatever is appropriate with the information.)